# Подсчет совпадений разных значений в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В mysql ведётся лог недоступности оборудования. Встала задача считать, сколько раз оборудование "падало" в заданном интервале.
Структура таблицы такая:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(20)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip          | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| power_state | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| power_time  | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

На данный момент подсчитываю количество падений весьма извращенным способом (получаю список ip из другой таблицы и делаю запрос в эту)
Понимаю, что можно сделать как-то по человечески, но как - не могу придумать..

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `device_data` WHERE `visible` = '1'"; //список ip
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
for ($c=0; $c<mysql_num_rows($result); $c++) {
    $f = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $ip=$f[ip];
    $down_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `power_data` 
        WHERE `ip` LIKE '$ip' AND `power_state` LIKE 'DOWN' 
        AND `power_time` > '$datefrom' AND `power_time` < '$dateto'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($down_query);

    echo "
<tr>
    <td>
        $ip
    </td>
    <td>
        $num_rows
    </td>
</tr>";
}
```

Как результат - задача выполнена, но долго. Помогите оптимизировать, либо пните в нужную сторону.

Comment: Zayac, у вас ipv4 или в перемешу с ipv6? В поле `power_state` есть возможность хранить значение в цифровом виде?

Comment: Только ipv4, В принципе UP/DOWN можно сменить на 0/1

Comment: А данных много в БД?

Comment: На данный момент 25147 записей, разных ip, по которым ведутся логи 1632 штук

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1. JOIN

В принципе, про джойн уже написали. Это должно быть на автомате - если запрос в цикле, то джойн. Делается он совсем несложно - берутся две таблицы и связываются по общему полю:

```
SELECT ip FROM power_data p, device_data d WHERE p.ip=d.ip
```

и вот мы уже получили сводную таблицу, в которой к первой дописаны данные из второй, подтянутые по ip=ip (причем из первой данные не берутся, если во второй нет связи. За это отвечает тип джойна). Дальше к этому запросу можно дописывать любые операторы как обычно. d и p - это *алиасы*, для сокращения писанины.

### 2. GROUP BY

Теперь GROUP BY. Это ведь совсем несложно. Сгруппировать по одинаковым IP и попросить базу посчитать количество вхождений по ним. То есть - получить ровно те данные, которые нам нужны: ip - цифра, ip - цифра...

Причем сделано это будет внутри самой БД, без необходимости гонять все данные между скриптом и базой:

```
SELECT p.ip, count(1) cnt 
    FROM power_data p, device_data d 
    WHERE p.ip=d.ip
        AND p.power_state=0 AND d.visible = 1
        AND p.power_time > [datefrom] AND p.power_time < [dateto]
    GROUP BY p.ip
```

### EXPLAIN и индексы.

Здесь без готовой базы (причем заполненной данными - это важно), получить правильную аналитику не получится. Генерить тестовые данные - настолько далеко мой альтруизм не распространяется. Но обычно оптимизация запросов - это отдельный вопрос, который автору велят задавать отдельным постом, включив все запросы, а так же вывод команды, которую надо скопировать 1-в-1 и выполнить в консоли или phpmyadmin

```
3. EXPLAIN [тестируемый запрос]
```

Но в принципе можно дать пару рекомендаций и так: Надо смотреть в колонки `key` - актуально задействованный ключ, и `rows` - количество затронутых запросом строк. Причем **надо перемножить** между собой все цифры из этой колонки. В колонке `key` должно быть хоть что-то, а в колонке `rows` - как можно меньшее число.

Если наугад, чисто из опыта - то в `device_data` для этого запроса пригодился бы индекс по `ip,visible`, а в `power_data` - по `power_state,power_time`

Эти первые три пункта - **главное**. С них должна начинаться любая оптимизация и именно они дадут принципиальный прирост производительности, пренебрегать ими нельзя.

### 4. Мелкие оптимизации

Идея сократить размер данных в таблице - здравая. В первую очередь она касается самого IPv4 адреса, который представляет из себя ничто иное, как обычный 4-байтовый int. И может храниться в колонке соответствующего типа. Для конвертации в mysql есть функции `inet_aton()` и `inet_ntoa()`.
**Разумеется**, никаких проблем с WHERE эти функции не создают. Ну, то есть, если самому не тупить и не писать `WHERE inet_ntoa(ip) = '127.0.0.1'`, применяя функцию к каждой записи в таблице.
Применять её надо к константе, оставляя поле как есть:

```
WHERE ip = inet_aton('127.0.0.1')
```

и индекс будет работать прекрасно.

Также можно вместо слов писать в статусы цифры, и таким образом сократить размер всей записи до 16 байт!

### 5. PDO

Как говорилось выше и все время говорится на всех сайтах и форумах, надо от от функций mysql переходить к использованию PDO preparеd statements. Это даст сразу ТРИ эффекта:

1. пропадут любые ошибки, вызванные неверными данными.
2. SQL-инъекции окажутся на свалке истории*)
3. (о чем чаще всего не знают) множество рутинных операций станут выполняться проще и меньшим количеством кода.

Главное правило при работе с PDO - все запросы, в которых используются какие-либо переменные, должны выполняться строго через prepare()/execute(), а вместо переменных в запрос должны вставляться пейсхолдеры:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT inet_ntoa(p.ip) ip, count(1) cnt 
    FROM power_data p, device_data d 
    WHERE p.ip=d.ip
        AND p.power_state=0 AND d.visible = 1
        AND p.power_time > ? AND p.power_time < ?
    GROUP BY p.ip");
$stmt->execute(array($datefrom, $dateto));
$stats = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

в результате мы получим массив вида `[ip => cnt]` который очень удобно потом вывести в шаблоне:

```
?>
<? foreach ($stat as $ip => $cnt)
<tr>
    <td><?=$ip?></td>
    <td><?=$cnt?></td>
</tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

---

*) утверждение не совсем верно, поскольку есть [случаи, в которых PDO не справляется](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#in)

---

PS. Вот меня часто ругают за то отношение, которое я высказываю по отношению к сообществу пхп в целом, и к тем его представителям, которые отвечают на вопроса на SO.

Ну скажите, какое может быть отношение, если три ответа, из которых

- один переливает из пустого в порожнее: спросив, не ip ли v4 хранится в базе (как будто в варчар(15) можно запихнуть ipv6), потом, когда читатель ждёт уж рифмы **"INT"**... предлагает тот же варчар, только в профиль. Плюс немасштабируемый IN. Плюс куча мелкой непринципиальной косметики, причем не видно различия между действительно важными вещами и мелочевкой.
- а другие два смогли-таки в джойн, но груп бай уже не осилили.

Потом в вопрос придут добрые самаритяне, исправят "несправедливо" проставленные минусы, и все останутся довольны, а на просторах сети останется еще одна бессмысленная страница.

Comment: +1 за ответ, -1 за офтопичную критику других ответов.

Comment: Я думаю, что если вы _просто_ дадите хороший ответ, и объясните, что нужно, а что не нужно делать, и почему, всем и так станет понятно, что ваш ответ хороший.

Comment: В итоге получился такой код: 
`
    SELECT *,COUNT(*) as 'cnt' FROM 'power_data' 
        INNER JOIN  'device_data' ON 'power_data'.'ip'='device_data'.'ip'
        WHERE 'power_data'.'power_state'='DOWN'
        AND 'power_data'.'power_time' > '[datefrom]'
        AND 'power_data'.'power_time' < '[dateto]'
        AND 'device_data'.'visible' = 1
    GROUP BY 'power_data'.'ip'
`

Comment: @Shorty : Стоит отметить, что при использовании mysql функции `inet_pton` в условие `WHERE` не будет использоваться индекс. В php существует аналогичная функция [inet_pton()](http://php.net/inet_pton). Если бы MySQL поддерживал функциональные индексы, как PostgreSQL, то всё это и многое другое, стало бы возможным. Для ipv6 можно задействовать [BINARY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5133610/2156062).

Answer (score 0):

**По запросам:**

- Максимально избегайте **запросы в цикле**. Для перечисление, существует оператор `IN`
- если у вас идёт точное совпадение, то в `LIKE` нет необходимости: `power_state='DOWN'`

**По структуре:**

`ip` - если ipv4, то `CHAR(15)`. Непринципиально `VARCHAR(15)` или `CHAR(15)`, но тип `CHAR` используется, когда известна длина поля. В вашем случае, это 15.

`power_state`: `tinyint(1) UNSIGNED`, т.е состояние желательно хранить в цифрах: DOWN - 0, UP - 1. Тогда запрос будет выглядить: `power_state=0`

`power_time`: лучше хранить в `timestamp`, хотя непринципиально. Тип `int` удобен при миграции с одной СУБД на другую. `timestamp` же позволяет использовать функции по работе с датами на уровне СУБД да и логично смотрится.

В первом запросе:

```
SELECT * FROM `device_data` WHERE `visible` = 1
```

поскольку вас интересуют только `ip`, то оптимальным по памяти будет указание необходимого столбца:

```
SELECT `ip` FROM `device_data` WHERE `visible` = 1
```

Аналогично и по второму запросу, если в этом существует необходимость.

Со всеми изменениями итоговый запрос будет выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM `power_data` 
    WHERE `ip` IN ('127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2') 
    AND `power_state`=0
    AND `power_time` > '$datefrom' 
    AND `power_time` < '$dateto'
```

Таким образом, вы получаете два атомарных запроса. Если есть необходимость использовать связанность, то @lDrakonl показал, как это сделать:

```
  SELECT power_data.* FROM `power_data` 
    INNER JOIN  `device_data` ON `power_data`.`ip`=`device_data`.`ip`
    WHERE `power_data`.`power_state`=0
    AND `power_data`.`power_time` > '$datefrom'
    AND `power_data`.`power_time` < '$dateto'
    AND `device_data`.`visible` = 1
```

> Если очень много связей, то оптимально будет использование именно атомарных запросов.

**По поводу индексов:**

Необходимо выставить для всех полей, которые участвуют в условие `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, агрегаторов `MIN` и `MAX`, а также в связях `JOIN`. Существуют нюансы при которых индекс может быть не задействован (некоторые связки `WHERE` и `JOIN`) - избыточный индексы, который весит в памяти наравне с остальными. В вашем случае, индексы уместны для полей: `power_data.power_state`, `power_data.power_time` и `device_data.visible`. При атомарном подходе дополнительно на `power_data.ip`.

Существует возможность попасть в так называемый **покрывающий индекс** - обращение будет происходить не к самим данным, которые лежат на диске, а только к индексу. Смотря какие поля вы укажите в `SELECT`. Требуется те поля на которых имеется индекс.

И да, используйте [**PDO**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/) вместо процедур:

- подготовленные выражение, которые позволят вам избежать SQL Injection
- `mysql-query` и иже с ними помечены, [как deprecated](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле я не знаком ни с PHP ни с MySql, но возможно мои советы сомгут Вам помочь. 
Если я правильно понял, то  сначала получаете список всех IP и потом выполняете в цикле много запросов по каждому из IP. Кажется,
 что имеет смысл сразу попробовать объединить все в 1 запрос.

Он будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `power_data` pd inner join  `device_data` dd on pd.`ip`=dd.`ip`
   WHERE /*`ip` LIKE '$ip' AND*/ `power_state` LIKE 'DOWN' 
   AND pd.`power_time` > '$datefrom' AND pd.`power_time` < '$dateto' 
   and dd.`visible` = '1'
```

Так же условие     `power_state LIKE 'DOWN'` возможно следует заменить на     `power_state = 'DOWN'` ? Не знаю, как в MySql, но в других БД это может немного ускорить запрос

Comment: Вопрос к господам минусующим. Прокомментируйте хотя бы, чем плохо мой совет?